# .NET MVC class object for linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a class

```
public class AClass 
{
     public string AA { get; set; }
     public string AB { get; set; }
}
```

In a LINQ

```
var x = (from oo in db.AClass 
         select new AClass() { AA = oo.AA, BB = oo.BB }).ToList();
```

The question: can `AA` be only accessible inside the initiation of LINQ? After that I want it to be private? So API call or other developer will not access this field.

If this class is not applied in LINQ, I can put AA into the constructor. Unfortunately, LINQ doesn't support constructor with parameter.

So I wondered if there's any trick to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't initialize a private property using the initialization list. With C# 9 with the `init` keyword, you can initialize public properties that are read only. If you're wanting it to be private, use a constructor.

Comment: i cant use constructor as the class is applied in LINQ and it throw error "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities" if i use a constructor with params

Comment: There are some drawbacks to doing the following (i.e. not being fully lazy), but you can call `ToList` on `db.AClass`, which will give you normal `Linq` operations.

Comment: @Hayden, I am using a raw linq instead of calling the function such as .Where or .FirstOfDefault due to requirement of getting few values from more than 1 associated tables. I have to select the object first before ToList(), or I need to separate the class initialization & query selection or assigning the value of properties twice.

Answer (score 0):

> The question: can AA be only accessible inside the initiation of LINQ? After that I want it to be private? So API call or other developer will not access this field.

Designing (non web) API's is quite different than normal windows, service, web or mobile programming. The idea is not to use any datatypes that can be changed on the client-side.

Take `List<T>` in your question for example, end-users can add, remove etc. You're much better off using an `IEnumerable<T>`.

This way its private to other developers and as an API call response can't be tampered with.